# Redirect console output to dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, redirect, console

What function or functions can you use redirect console output to a data frame in R? As an example, the following code associated with the mgcv package produces a set of diagnostics used to assist in model selection of GAMs:

```
gam.check(gamout, type=c("deviance")
```

It produces the following output

```
Method: GCV   Optimizer: magic
Smoothing parameter selection converged after 7 iterations.
The RMS GCV score gradient at convergence was 1.988039e-07 .
The Hessian was positive definite.
Model rank =  10 / 11 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

          k'  edf k-index p-value
s(year) 9.00 3.42    1.18    0.79
```

I'm interested in redirecting this output to a data frame I can process into a table I can output and actually use rather than read off the console. I don't need specifics just functions I might be able to use to start solving the problem. Once I have the function, I can work my way through the specifics.

sink() this apparently outputs to a txt file which...I suppose I could use this function and then re-import the output but that seems like a pretty stupid solution.

Answer (score 0):

The functions I would start with are `class(gam.check(gamout, type="deviance"))` and `names(gam.check(gamout, type="deviance"))`. This should help you figure out what the data structure is and then how to extract elements of it.

Comment: Well ...thanks for the suggestion but that seems to just produce a repeat of the same output??

Comment: I could give more specific help if you would create a reproducible example. Create a small dataframe with fake data, then fit a gam, the run `gam.check`. Include that code in your question so that we can recreate same gam object you're working with. It's always a good idea to use the reprex package to make sure your example is reproducible.

Comment: Gregory I fixed the problem by using k.check instead of gam.check. It produces a list I can manipulate. Thanks again. I appreciate any help at all whether it proves directly applicable to the problem or not.

Comment: @KodiakMFL You could post your own answer with a reproducible solution and accept it!